# How to sort a list column in power shell and update list in share point 2010

Tags: development, powershell, sharepoint-server

using powershell script how to sort a list column before update a list  item.

here i created a document library and uploaded some documents and want to update ProcessNo column based on Created-Seconds column,
so how i sort created-Seconds column in Dec order and update processno.

like : old documents the processno should start from 1.

2/3/2015  1
3/4/2015  2

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

$webURL = "http://tspmcwfe:91" $listName = "Courts"

Get the SPWeb object and save it to a variable

$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL

$list = $web.Lists[$listName] 
$items = $list.items



Go through all items

foreach($item in $items)

{

$item["ProcessNo"] = 1
 }



$item.Update()



$web.Dispose()
```

value.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The loop should be like this

```
foreach($item in $items) {
    $item["ProcessNo"] = 1
    $item.Update()
}
```